# ASP Sorting Encrypted Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, encryption

The data in my database are encrypted. When I print it on a gridview it goes like this:

On my mark up:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" SelectMethod="GetParents" ... >
     <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# GetDecrypted((string)Eval("LastName"))%>'
                runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

on my code:

```
protected string GetDecrypted(string Decrypt)
{
  //returns a decrypted version
   return ENCRYPTION.Decrypt(Decrypt);
}
```

This is my Select Method

```
public IQueryable<Parent> GetParents()
    {
        InfantRecordContext db = new InfantRecordContext();
        int id = int.Parse(Session["DoctorID"].ToString());
        return db.Parent.Where(p => p.DoctorID == id);
    }
```

The problem is, when I sort the columns, it sorts the encrypted data not the decrypted, is ther a way I can sort the decrypted data displayed on my gridview?

Or is there a way that I can decrypt the field before sorting?

Comment: Why not decrypt it before you even bind it to your GridView?

Comment: What are you using as a datasource for the gridview?

Comment: Hi @mason, I updated my post, I would really appreciate if you'll post your idea on decrypting before binding it to the Gridview. I know how to return using select all but i don't know how to select the fields one by one and decrypting them first. Thank you!

Comment: @DVK Hi! I updated my post and added the part that I used for the Select Method thank you!

Comment: I edited the question to make it more apparent what specifically you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply decrypt in the event, then manually perform your sorting.

The Grid View should actually contain: `GridView.Sorting` event.  The purpose:

> The Sorting event is raised when the hyperlink to sort a column is
>   clicked, but before the `GridView` control handles the sort operation.
>   This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a
>   custom routine, such as canceling the sorting operation, whenever this
>   event occurs. A `GridViewSortEventArgs` object is passed to the
>   event-handling method, which enables you to determine the sort
>   expression for the column and to indicate that the selection operation
>   should be canceled. To cancel the selection operation, set the Cancel
>   property of the `GridViewSortEventArgs` object to true.

The code example would be as follows:

```
  protected void TaskGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
  {

    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;

    if (dt != null)
    {

      //Sort the data.
      dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
      TaskGridView.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
      TaskGridView.DataBind();
    }

  }

  private string GetSortDirection(string column)
  {

    // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
    string sortDirection = "ASC";

    // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
    string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

    if (sortExpression != null)
    {
      // Check if the same column is being sorted.
      // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
      if (sortExpression == column)
      {
        string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
        if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
        {
          sortDirection = "DESC";
        }
      }
    }

    // Save new values in ViewState.
    ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
    ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

    return sortDirection;
  }
```